# Kubernetes change multi-master node to single master node on failure

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, internal-load-balancer

Is there any way to convert/change multi-master nodes(3 masters, HA & LB) to single master in stacked *etcd* configuration?

In 3 master nodes, it only tolerates 1 failure right?
So if 2 of these master node goes down, the control plane wouldn't work.

what I need to do is convert these 3masters to a single master? is there any way to do this to minimalize the downtime of the control plane? (in case the other 2 masters need some time to turn back on)

the test I've done:
I've tried to restore *etcd* snapshot to a fully different environment with a new setup of 1 master & 2 workers, and it seems to work fine.. the status of the other 2 master nodes is not ready, 2 worker node is ready, and request to *api-server* is working normally.

But, if I restore *etcd* snapshot to the original environment.. after resetting the last master node with *kubeadm reset*, the cluster seems to be broken.. the status of 2 workers is not ready, seems like it has different certificates.

any suggestion on how to make this works?

> UPDATE: so apparently, I could restore etcd snapshot directly without
> doing "kubeadm reset", even if doing reset.. as long as we update the
> certificates, the cluster should be restored successfully.
>
> BUT now I run into a different issue, after restoring the etcd
> snapshot.. everything works fine, so basically I want to add a new
> Control Plane to this Cluster, the current node status is:
> master1 ready
>
> master2 not-ready
>
> master3 not-ready
>
> before I add new CP, I removed the 2 failed master node from the
> cluster. after removing it I tried to join new CP to cluster, and the
> join process stuck at :
>
> [etcd] Waiting for the new etcd member to join the cluster. This can
> take up to 40s [kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
>
> the original master node is broken again, now I can't access the
> api-server. do you guys have any idea what's going wrong?